# Why Yosemite calculator works wrong?

Tags: macos, calculator

Tried to get cube-root(using internal yosemite calculator) from 512 and got 7.9(9). Is it some kind of approximation? What should i do to get exact result?[image: screenshot with wrong result]

Comment: Pretty picture.  In older OS X version's Calculator.app you can set the precision under View => Decimal Place.  Setting the number to less that the maximum should cause rounding.  (And of course I had to go from 15 digits to 13 to get 7.9999999999999999 to round).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a common side effect of floating point arithmetic operations.

Check out this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Floating-point_arithmetic_operations

To fix this on Mac OS Yosemite:

1. Open the Calculator App
2. From the **View** menu, select **Decimal Places**, and then select **14**.

Also check out this article on how similar problems show up in Microsoft Excel thanks to floating point arithmetic operations: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214118

Answer (score 10):

When you say an "exact" result in this case, you're talking about getting an integer result when the correct answer is an integer.

#### Integer results vs. calculation methods

There are several approaches used for calculating different functions, depending on the function.  **Whether or not you get an integer answer doesn't depend on the specific numbers involved.**  It depends on the calculation method used for that function.

If the calculation method uses integers, you can get an integer result.  Otherwise, you likely won't get an integer answer just because the calculation was applied to a specific number for which the correct answer happens to be an integer.

- Functions that can be performed with **integer arithmetic** will produce an integer answer.
- Functions that involve roots, logs, trig functions, and many others are generally calculated using **floating point arithmetic**.  This often involves values that the computer can't represent precisely, so the result can be affected by rounding or truncation error.
- For some functions, there isn't a practical way to directly calculate the answer.  These use **approximations** (either a simplified calculation that gets you very close, or iterations of a formula until the error is below some threshold).

#### Precision

The non-integer calculations will produce a result that is to the precision afforded by the number of significant digits available.  The precision is good enough to not make a difference in any practical, real-world application.

But, as you point out in comments, the result isn't exact, and you could say that it's mathematically "incorrect" because it isn't exact.  That's a limitation of our current technology.  It's as close an answer as you can get with that hardware and software.

For context, though, consider that prior to the general availability of "business class" personal computers (late-1970s) and pocket calculators (early 1970s), the basis for calculation was largely **published tables of numerical values** (typically to four or five decimal places), or **slide rules** (a little better than three significant digits).  That level of precision was adequate to build the modern world up to that time.

#### Displaying the result

Some software will let you set the number of significant digits to display, and results will typically be rounded at that level.  In your example, the result would display as 8.  I don't use a Mac, but user388043's answer describes how to access this on the Yosemite Calculator through the View menu.

Comment: But answer is mathematically wrong.. It's = 8,not 7.99 or 6

Comment: If there were an infinite number of decimal places, the answer would be correct.  The problem isn't that it is "wrong", it's that there aren't enough decimal places.  But it is damn close.  In the current math curriculum in schools, that would pass for the right answer.  For that matter, so would 6.

Comment: @Andrew *8 - 7.999999… = 0.000000…*, so there is no difference, assuming infinite decimal places.

Comment: @Andrew, I know you were never really satisfied with the explanation.  Going on two years later, it finally dawned on me how to explain it better.  Is this a clearer answer (if you still care)?

Comment: I understood what floating operation is from the start, but you can explain so other people may see it. What I wanted to know from the start is why apple decided to work with less accurate algorithm(in case of sqrt(512) 8 is always more correct then 7.9(9))

Comment: @Andrew, that's actually a different and interesting question, which I tried to hit on a little in the revision.  The answer to that basically comes down to "cost"/computer resources/speed and supply and demand.  You could get exact answers if you did something like for every function included in the calculator, have a table of cases where the answer is an integer and do a lookup first.  Another approach might be something like reverse successive approximations, where you do the floating point calculation. (cont'd)

Comment: If that comes out within some error limit of an integer, you test the integer to see if that produces the exact answer.  There are some ways you could accomplish it.  There's a "cost" for those approaches.  If enough people demanded that level of precision, some enterprising programmers would produce it (and who knows, there might be examples out there now).  The routines for the floating point calculations are well established and readily available, and adequate for most people and most cases.  So that's why all of the "consumer" calculator apps just use floating point calculations.